# Regex on grep command in linux

Tags: regex, linux, scripting, grep, command-line-interface

I have a file named test.txt
test file has the following content of just 4 lines in it:

```
d
dxx
xxd
xxdxx
```

when I try to use the following grep command on ununtu, it is giving me **no** output

```
$ grep 'd[^x]' test.txt
```

whereas I expect output to be:

```
d
xxd
```

Could any please explain me the reason for such behaviour

Comment: Do `grep -P 'd([^x]|$)'` this will work even if there is no char after `d` (`-P`  is for Perl regexes). Your expression expects a char not-x after d.

Comment: This might help: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
$ grep 'd$' file
d
xxd
```

Your solution doesn't work, because after `d`, there's nothing but end of line: `$`

Comment: Because after 'd', there's nothing but end of line: $

Answer (score 0):

I can solve that issue in 2 ways:

```
$grep 'd$' test.txt
d
xxd

$grep 'd\>' test.txt
d
xxd
```

*** But, Can anyone please explain why the following is not working***

```
$grep 'd[^x]' test.txt
no output
```

Comment: This should belongs as a comment, not a reply

Comment: Edit your original question rather than answering with a question